# XPath error for Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, xml-file

I want to get live data from a website. I select inspect and copy the XPath from where I want the data to import, but I get an #ERROR!.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.jamstockex.com/market-data/listed-companies/stock-performance/afs/latest","//span[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to get the results I desire.

When I enter:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.jamstockex.com/market-data/listed-companies/stock-performance/afs/latest","//tr")
```

I get results, but more data than I want to import.

In the screenshot from the website, I want to import from last traded price or the content from last two tables minus titles[image]

With the attached png is there a way to only import the figures and not the titles?

Comment: Please take a screenshot and highlight the field(s) you want retrieved.  Post the screenshot in your original post, please.

Comment: @BillHileman Hey I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following xpath will return the ten data columns on that page:

```
//div[@class='col-md-6']//td
```